# атрибут <a download="1.jpg" >Скачать</a> не работает в IE

Tags: javascript, html, html5, internet-explorer

при нажатии на ссылку IE спрашивает, *вы хотите позволить веб сайту открыть приложение на вашем компьютере* и предлагает выбрать из windows store

я не ставлю себе цель чтоб html5 сайт хорошо работал на IE, нужно хотя бы как нибудь) главное не в ущерб браузерам

```js
function download() {
  var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  this.href = dt;
};
downloadLnk.addEventListener('click', download, false);
```

```html
<a id="downloadLnk" download="img.jpg">Скачать</a>
```

Comment: Потому что он там не работает http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: и что мне делать

Comment: Забиться в угол и плакать. Можно попробовать написать самому, но тут одной клиентской частью не обойтись. Есть мерзкий костыль (сам не пробовал), подробности тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652750/any-fallback-client-side-solutions-for-the-html5-download-attribute

Answer (score -1):

```
var redirectWindow = window.open('img.jpg', '_self');
redirectWindow.location;
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Не могли бы добавить пару поясняющих слов, в чём заключается ваша мысль?